# Merging Multiple GLTF having some common nodes using gltf-transform

Tags: webgl, gltf

This issue is an Extension of [Multiple GLTF loading and Merging on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031422/multiple-gltf-loading-and-merging-on-server-side).

I am trying to merge multiple GLTF files that have some common nodes too.
The answer helped me for the merging the files and I combined the scenes by following code and it rendered perfectly

```js
const scenes = root.listScenes()
const scene0 = scenes[0]
root.setDefaultScene(scene0);
if (scenes.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 1; i < scenes.length; i++) {
        let scene = scenes[i];
        let nodes = scene.listChildren()
        for (let j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
            scene0.addChild(nodes[j]);
        }
    }
}

root.listScenes().forEach((b, index) => index > 0 ? b.dispose() : null);
```

My issue is all the data that was common in the GLTFs is duplicated and this will create issue in animation when root bones are required to change. Is there a way to merge so that the common nodes are not duplicated ? I am also trying for some custom merge.

```js
const gltfLoader = () => {
    const document = new Document();
    const root = document.getRoot();
    document.merge(io.read(filePaths[0]));
    let model;
    for (let i = 1; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
        const inDoc = new Document();
        inDoc.merge(io.read(filePaths[i]));
        model = inDoc.getRoot().listScenes()[0];
        model.listChildren().forEach((child) => {
            mergeStructure(root.listScenes()[0], child);
        });
    }

    io.write('output.gltf', document);
}

const mergeStructure = (parent, childToMerge) => {
    let contains = false;
    parent.listChildren().forEach((child) => {
        if (child.t === childToMerge.t && !contains && child.getName() === childToMerge.getName()) {

            childToMerge.listChildren().forEach((subChild) => {
                mergeStructure(child, subChild);
            });
            contains = true;
        }
    });
    if (!contains) {
        console.log("Adding " + childToMerge.getName() + " to  " + parent.getName() + "  as child")
        parent.addChild(childToMerge);
    }
}
```

But this merge is not working due to `Error: Cannot link disconnected graphs/documents`.
I am newbie to 3D modelling. Some direction would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're seeing above is occurring because the code attempts to move individual resources — e.g. [Nodes](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/classes/core.node.html) — from one glTF [Document](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/classes/core.document.html) to another. This isn't possible, each Document manages its resource graph internally, but an equivalent workflow would be:

1. Load N files and merge into one document (with N scenes).

```js
import { Document, NodeIO } from '@gltf-transform/core';

const io = new NodeIO();
const document = new Document();

for (const path of paths) {
  document.merge(io.read(path));
}
```

2. Iterate over all of the scenes, moving their children to some common scene:

```js
const root = document.getRoot();
const mainScene = root.listScenes()[0];

for (const scene of root.listScenes()) {
  if (scene === mainScene) continue;

  for (const child of scene.listChildren()) {
    // If conditions are met, append child to `mainScene`. 
    // Doing so will automatically detach it from the
    // previous scene.
  }

  scene.dispose();
}
```

3. Clean up any remaining unmerged resources.

```js
import { prune } from '@gltf-transform/functions';

await document.transform(prune());
```

Comment: Yes earlier I had added children of other scenes into mainScene but it gave me duplicate nodes. As a hackish workaround I have kept a map of <NodeName, Node> to keep the first occurence of each node of given Name and have replaced all the skeleton and joints nodes in the skins with the first occurence nodes. Meanwhile I will keep working on your suggestion and try to avoid adding duplicate nodes. Thanks :-)