# Exporting single OBJ out of multiple model URNs

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have implemented multiple models viewer using Autodesk forge. We are trying to achieve a functionality where users could select entities from different models from multi-model viewer and export a single obj file out of it.

but it seems, [Translate a Source File](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/task4-download-obj-file/#step-1-check-the-status-of-the-translation-job) API allows just a single model URN to be passed.
I'm looking for a way where I could create a single Obj from more than one model URN.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not built-in way to do that actually.
If you are working with NodeJS you can use glTF file format and follow this method :

- Convert your different models with [Forge-Convert-Utils](https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-convert-utils/docs/)
- Merge with [glTF-Transform](https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform) following this answer : [Multiple gltf loading and merging on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031422/multiple-gltf-loading-and-merging-on-server-side)

**glTF** is well supported now on many platforms and pretty efficient but if you really need **OBJ** you can use [assimpJS](https://github.com/kovacsv/assimpjs) (which is the JS port of [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp)) to convert your files.

Comment: I agree. While Forge allows you to aggregate multiple models in the viewer, it doesn't really "bake" multiple models into a single one. The approach suggested by Alex (converting individual Forge models to glTFs and then combining those) makes the most sense.